# Open source microservice visualization

Tags: docker, monitoring, network-monitoring

We run various microservices on rancher and kubernetes, and I am wondering if there are any open source projects that assist in visualizing network traffic between services to help detect dependencies. Similar to the project below

https://docs.netsil.com/

Comment: you can use promoteus to collect network metrics and then grafana for building visualization on metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I believe some of the monitoring tools like [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/availability-and-performance/kubernetes-monitoring/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=%2Bkubernetes%20%2Bmonitoring&utm_campaign=us-cloud-monitoring&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuPjm5urG2gIVhwOGCh2dQA5bEAAYAyAAEgINEfD_BwE) and [Scope](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope) show some neat stuff. This really depends on your platform (I'm assuming Kubernetes).

However, if you are running something else checkout [Visceral](https://github.com/Netflix/vizceral). Here is a neat video of it in [action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JctsPpgEsVs). It's more complicated to get up and going.